# Best way to move this dryer vent hookup?

Tags: hvac, dryer, ducts

I am adding a sink to my laundry room on the right hand side of my dryer. The washing machine and related plumbing is on the left hand side of the dryer, so in order to tap off the drain for the new sink I will need to move the dryer vent up about 2 feet. What's the best way to do this? This current vent appears to be a 6" diameter rigid duct that is reduced to a 4" duct at the very end. Initially this seems simple - cut the duct and move the right angle 4" part up 2 feet. The problem  is that then I would have no "collar" which is typically at the end of rigid ducting. Is there a recommended way to attach pieces of ducting together without a collar?

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need a collar.  The reducing piece is probably crimped to slip into the larger pipe so if you cut the pipe you're good.  You need to remove the tape to be sure.  But... Where is the vent connection on your dryer?  If it's in the bottom left of the rear wall I don't see what your plan is.  :(

Comment: You can get a crimping tool to make the collar on the cut duct, if needed. Or you replace the whole section of duct with a shorter one.